# non-parametric analysis

Tags: correlation, nonparametric

I have faced a problem with my data which have different disrtibution. I have some data that are scaled one so possible to do ordinary parametric analysis on them (ANOVA, Correlation, ...) and series of scored data which I have to do non-parametric analysis. now I would like to know whether there is a way to correlate these sets of data, to find any relationship between them?

Answer (score 0):

There are some measures of association proposed for that kind of variables. You could also categorize your continuous variables in order to make the analysis. Take a look at this sources:

[A Comparison of the Most Commonly Used Measures of Association for Doubly Ordered Square Contingency Tables via Simulation](http://www.stat-d.si/mz/mz8.1/goktas.pdf)

[Parameters behind “nonparametric” statistics](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=st0007)